# Javascript array creation in function

Tags: javascript

I'm not very familiar with Javascript and have come across something that I can't find an answer to so far, looking at the following code:

```
function gridWindow(visible) {
    this.name='grid';
    this.visible=visible;
    this.defn={ gridText: ['aString1', 11], gridProp: ['aString2', 1], gridTime: ['aString3', 4] };
    this.init();
}
```

My question is what is happening with this line from above:

```
this.defn={ gridText: ['aString1', 11], gridProp: ['aString2', 1], gridTime: ['aString3', 4] };
```

Is it creating an array? What do the numbers mean after each string (the 11, 1 and 4)?
How would I retrieve a value from this kind of array?

Thanks.

Comment: It is creating an array... but I don't think we will be able to answer what are those numbers means without seeing how it is used

Comment: `{ gridText: ['aString1', 11] }` creates a Javascript *object* with a property called *gridText* that has as its value an *array* with two entries. What the numbers mean is impossible to say.

Comment: Take a look at the `init` function that is being called. It probably access these values in `this.defn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line :

```
this.defn={ gridText: ['aString1', 11], gridProp: ['aString2', 1], gridTime: ['aString3', 4] };
```

**this.defn** is a **json object** which contains keys :

> gridText , gridProp , gridTime

These keys are **json Arrays** with two values in it .

If you want to get values of **gridText** , you can get it like this :

```
this.defn.gridText[0] // it will return 'aString1'
this.defn.gridText[1] // it will return 11
```

Answer (score 0):

its not array,  it is and object with key value pairs and values are arrays

you can get the value as `this.defn.gridText`.
This will return you array `['aString1', 11]`

Comment: or `this.defn.gridText[1]` to get at the `11`.